# Wordpress Elementor Widget Development JavaScript not loaded in Editor mode correctly

Tags: wordpress, elementor

i want to create an Elementor-Widget with al slick Slider as JavaScript / Jquery. I can add the elements correctly in ELementor Editor Mode, but the Slider didn`t work there. The Slides will shown among themselves. When i add a alert in the javascript file after the check that the element slider is still there, its not work, before the check its works fine. I think the Element will not load correctly in the editor mode...? Have someone an idea what i can do that the slider works also in the editor-mode?

Here the JavaScript-Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
if ($(".slider").length) {
    alert("Test");
    $(".slider").css({"opacity" :"1"});
    $(".slider").slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        arrows: true,
        speed: 1000,
        fade: false,
        dots: false,
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><i class="arrow fa fa-minus"></i></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><i class="arrow fa fa-plus"></i></button>',
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 992,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    dots: true
                }
            }
        ]

    });
};
```

Here the Code of the PHP Widget File:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Astestimonials class.
 *
 ....
 */

namespace ElementorAstestimonials\Widgets;

use Elementor\Widget_Base;
use Elementor\Controls_Manager;

// Security Note: Blocks direct access to the plugin PHP files.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || die();

/**
 * Astestimonials widget class.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
class Astestimonials extends Widget_Base {
    /**
     * Class constructor.
     *
     * @param array $data Widget data.
     * @param array $args Widget arguments.
     */
    public function __construct( $data = array(), $args = null ) {
        parent::__construct( $data, $args );
        $plugin = get_plugin_data( __FILE__, false, false );

        wp_register_style( 'astestimonialscss', plugins_url( '/assets/css/astestimonials.css', ELEMENTOR_ASTESTIMONIALS ), array(), '1.0.0' );
        wp_register_script( 'astestimonialsjs', plugins_url( '/assets/js/astestimonials.js', ELEMENTOR_ASTESTIMONIALS ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the widget name.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @return string Widget name.
     */
    public function get_name() {
        return 'astestimonials';
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the widget title.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @return string Widget title.
     */
    public function get_title() {
        return __( 'astestimonials', 'elementor-astestimonials' );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the widget icon.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @return string Widget icon.
     */
    public function get_icon() {
        return 'eicon-facebook-comments';
    }




    /**
     * Retrieve the list of categories the widget belongs to.
     *
     * Used to determine where to display the widget in the editor.
     *
     * Note that currently Elementor supports only one category.
     * When multiple categories passed, Elementor uses the first one.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @return array Widget categories.
     */
    public function get_categories() {
        return array( 'artisolution-addons' );
    }

    /**
     * Enqueue styles.
     */
    public function get_style_depends() {
        return array( 'astestimonialscss' );
    }

    public function get_script_depends() {
        return array( 'astestimonialsjs');

    }

    /**
     * Register the widget controls.
     *
     * Adds different input fields to allow the user to change and customize the widget settings.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access protected
     */
    protected function _register_controls() {
        $this->start_controls_section(
            'section_content',
            array(
                'label' => __( 'Content', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
            )
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'slides',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Slides', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
                'fields' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'content',
                        'label'   => __( 'Content', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                        'type'    => Controls_Manager::WYSIWYG,
                        'default' => __( 'Content', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'name',
                        'label'   => __( 'Name', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                        'type'    => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                        'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Beispielname', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                        'default' => __( 'Name', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'job',
                        'label'   => __( 'Job / Company', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                        'type'    => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                        'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Beispieljob', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                        'default' => __( 'Job', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'image',
                        'label' => esc_html__( 'Choose Image', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::MEDIA,
                        'default' => [
                            'url' => \Elementor\Utils::get_placeholder_image_src(),
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'default' => [
                    [
                        'content' => esc_html__( 'List Item #1', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                        'name' => esc_html__( 'Beispielname #1', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                        'job' => esc_html__( 'Beispiejob #1', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                    ],
                    [
                        'content' => esc_html__( 'List Item #2', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                        'name' => esc_html__( 'Beispielname #2', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                        'job' => esc_html__( 'Beispiejob #2', 'elementor-astestimonials' ),
                    ],
                ],
                'title_field' => '{{{ name }}}',
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();
    }

    /**
     * Render the widget output on the frontend.
     *
     * Written in PHP and used to generate the final HTML.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access protected
     */
    protected function render() {
        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
        ?>

        <div class="slider">
            <?php foreach ( $settings['slides'] as $index => $item ) : ?>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div class="review-wrap">
                        <div class="review-text 11">
                            <?php if ( '' != $item['content'] ) {
                                echo $item['content'];
                            } ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviewer">
                            <?php if ( '' != $item['image']['url'] ): ?>
                                <div class="avatar"
                                 style="background-image: url('<?php echo $item['image']['url']; ?>');"></div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="reviewer-info">
                                <h4 class="name"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></h4>
                                <p><?php echo $item['job']; ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- //author -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div><!-- //review-slider -->

        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Render the widget output in the editor.
     *
     * Written as a Backbone JavaScript template and used to generate the live preview.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access protected
     */
    protected function _content_template() {
        ?>

        <div class="slider">
            <#
            if ( settings.slides ) {
            _.each( settings.slides, function( item, index ) {
            #>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div class="review-wrap">
                        <div class="review-text 11">
                            <# if ( item.content != '' ) { #>
                                {{{ item.content }}}
                            <# } #>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviewer">
                            <# if ( item.image.url != '' ) { #>
                                <div class="avatar"
                                     style="background-image: url('{{ item.image.url }}');"></div>
                            <# } #>
                            <div class="reviewer-info">
                                <h4 class="name">{{{ item.name }}}</h4>
                                <p>{{{ item.job }}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- //author -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            <#
            } );
            }
            #>
        </div><!-- //review-slider -->


        <?php
    }
}
```

Here the Image of the Editor-Mode:
[Image Editor-Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUhcQ.png)

Here the Code of the JavaScript file for the Editor:

```
(function ($, elementor) {
"use strict";


var myDataCollection = {
    init: function () {
        var widgets = {
            "astestimonials": myDataCollection.AsTestimonials,
        };
        $.each(widgets, function (widget, callback) {
            elementor.hooks.addAction("frontend/element_ready/" + widget, callback);
        });
    },

    AsTestimonials: function ($scope) {
        $scope.find('.slider').hide();
        alert("Test");
    },

};

$(window).on("elementor/frontend/init", myDataCollection.init);
```

})(jQuery, window.elementorFrontend);

Answer (score 1):

Enqueue your JS file like this.

```html
add_action( 'elementor/frontend/before_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );

function enqueue_scripts()
{
   wp_enqueue_script( 'elementor-script', get_template_directory_uri( __FILE__ ) . '/assets/js/elementor.js', array( 'jquery', 'elementor-frontend' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

Now follow the first answer. I hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: That i have done and the script sucessfully loaded, i have checked it with a alert... But the Code inside the function didn`t work. Have you any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your enqueue Javascript doesn't load inside the elementor editor. For loading javascript, you have to follow some easy steps.

1. Enqueue your javascript with dependency elementor-frontend.

   wp_enqueue_script( 'script-handle', 'path/to/file.js', [ 'elementor-frontend' ], '1.0.0', true );
2. Now you will get a javascript hook elementor/frontend/init that loads your javascript inside the elementor.
   For snippet code, you can use this.

```js
(function ($, elementor) {
  "use strict";

  var myDataCollection = {
    init: function () {
      var widgets = {
        "back-to-top.default": myDataCollection.Back_To_Top,
      };
      $.each(widgets, function (widget, callback) {
        elementor.hooks.addAction("frontend/element_ready/" + widget, callback);
      });
    },

    Back_To_Top: function ($scope) {
      $scope.find('.BackTo').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body, html').animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        }, 1500)
      });
      $(window).on("scroll", function () {
        var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop(),
          docHeight = $(document).height() / 2;

        if (scrolltop > docHeight) {
          $scope.fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
          $scope.fadeOut("slow");
        }
      });
    },

  };
  $(window).on("elementor/frontend/init", myDataCollection.init);
})(jQuery, window.elementorFrontend);
```

Explanation of the above code :
I wrote the above code for Back to the top widget. my widget name is back-to-top. First I am taking an Immediately-invoked Function and I take 2 parameters as I enqueue my script with 2 dependency elementor-frontend and jquery so I will get back 2 parameters. For my code reusability, I make an object myDataCollection.otherwise we can do it like that. follow the below code.

```
elementor.hooks.addAction("frontend/element_ready/" + "back-to-top.default", "funtion_name");
```

It works fine but for multiple widgets, I make the first approach.
inside the object, I take a function init. inside init I take another object widget. widget is responsible for taking widget name and function name. after that I loop through it. so that we don't need to hook our widget again and again. Now I am explaining my callback function. Inside Callback, you will get a parameter like $scope.$scope is your actual widget. When your widget drags and drops inside the editor you will get the $scope.You will find your widget markup inside $scope.Now write your custom code for your widget and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you really much for your help. The registering for the Script works fine and to load the javascript file is also good, but the rest of the script i don`t understand. Please have a look to my changes in my answer. In the comment i cant write enough code...

Comment: I added an explanation with my answer. Maybe It will help you to understand the other scripts as well.

Comment: Thanks, i understand what you mean, but my Code wont work. Could you please have a short look at my code? I have posted it in my article at the end. There must be something wrong. The alert wont shown to me and the hide also wont work...

Comment: after widget name default is important. your handle should be astestimonials.default. but you wrote only astestimonials.

Comment: I have checked it also with default, But nothing Happens